# WIFI not turned on

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a desktop system. Previously tried to "wireless" connect my new printer.  Worked some and then stopped. I then just connected via wire.  Recently received a Amazon Echo which requires hookup to WIFI.  I ran the app, and nothing happened.  In checking (troubleshooting) network, I came up with a check of the network adapter and the check said "wifi not turned on".  How do I turn WIFI back on?  I am running Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Go to the Start Menu and select Control Panel.
- Click the Network and Internet category and then select Networking and Sharing Centre.
- From the options on the left-hand side, select Change adapter settings.
- Right-click on the icon for Wireless Connection and click enable. You'll now be able to connect to a Wi-Fi network from the Network and Sharing centre.

[Source](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/3279135/how-to-turn-wireless-connectivity-on-or-off-in-windows-7/) with pictures!